# Is there a library to make `'evil-goto-mark` restore the screen position of the marker?

Tags: evil, window, scrolling, window-point

I use emacs and evil. If I set a marker using `'evil-set-marker`, scroll elsewhere in the file, and then execute `'evil-goto-mark` or `'evil-goto-mark-line`, the window will scroll back until the position I’ve jumped to is visible, but will not return it to the same *screen position*. For example, the line I started from may have been the 3rd line from the top of the window, but will not necessarily be that anymore.

Is there a library that will restore windows to the same screen position when I execute `'evil-goto-mark` or `'evil-goto-mark-line`? For an additional refinement, I would like this behaviour only if jumping to the marker involves scrolling.

From a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-preserve-the-visual-height-of-the-cursor-after-an-operation), it looks like what I want to happen is for evil to store `(window-start)` when making a marker, and then set it again (using `'set-window-start`) when jumping to that marker. I will probably code this up now that I know this, but I would still like to know if there is a library that will handle it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Save and restore the value of `point` in the window you're interested in.

- Function `window-point` gives you the current value for a given window.
- Function `set-window-point` sets the value for a given window.

Comment: I don’t believe this answers my question. `point` is the position of the cursor relative to the start of the file, not relative to the screen. If I run `(set-window-start (get-buffer-window) (+ 20 (window-start)))`, for example, the *screen position* of the current line changes (it moves up towards the top of the screen), but `point` remains the same – therefore restoring it is not sufficient.

Comment: To explain a bit further: say `point` is on the last line visible in my window. I save it (say its value is 19900), and then scroll down further into the file. If I call `(set-window-point (get-buffer-window) 19900)`, `point` will be successfully restored to its previous value, but will now be on the first line visible in my window – I would like it instead to be on the last line, as that's the line it was on before I navigated away. When I jump back with `'evil-goto-mark`, I would like the visible screen area to be the same as it was when I called `'evil-set-marker`.

Comment: In that case, do what you say in your question's last paragraph. That assumes that your window remains the same height. (There's no function `set-window-end`.)